# How to have a String[] attribute in a Community Builder Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder, design

So my component looks like this:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="toyList" type="String[]" required="true" />
</aura:component>
```

The idea is that the User, when putting it into a Community Builder could enter any Strings they wanted to put into toyList (like "ball" and "cards").

However the community builder looks like this (personal details censored):
[image]

When I click "Select" it looks like this:
[image]

Is there anyway to let the User just enter what strings they want as toys? And if there isn't, what workarounds should I do (and how)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The design:component currently supports only Boolean,Strings,Integer and the picklist values .

The multipicker is not supported and hence the best possible solution would be to allow user to enter as comma separated or colon separated values and write javascript code to generate an array by using split function .

The other alternative is obviously build your own component and then use events to wire them to the necessary components .